# missing broadcast intents when the device is rotated?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

We have a network client application, and we are trying to validate our approach to processing  responses from the server in conjunction with device rotation. essentially, we do this,

1. activity registers a receiver for network responses
2. activity initiates a network operation by starting an intent service
3. service responds by broadcasting an intent it's finished

our (perceived) problem is that when the device is rotated, the activity is destroyed / recreated. during the time between when the activity's receiver is unregistered in `onPause()` and when it's re-registered in `onResume()`, we may have missed the intent that is broadcast by the service.

is this a real problem?

if so, we have hypothesized the following solution,

1. first, don't use intents to communicate between activity and service
2. create two blocking queues: network requests and responses in say the application class
3. service starts a thread that `take()`'s from the request queue
4. activity starts a thread that `take()`'s from the  response queue
5. activity `offer()`'s to the request queue when it wants to start a network operation
6. service `offer()`'s to the response queue when post the result of a network operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this can happen in rare circumstances but it will happens for sure if the user receives a call. Again your activity will be paused and then resumed, If the user talks for a long time your activity will loose a bunch of broadcasts from the service.

My advice is that you must not use broadcasts to do two way communications between application's in situations that a response from a component such as a service, requires immediate attention. What mechanism you will use is depending from the situation. In my latest project I am using a service in order to update an app-widget, in this scenario I am using static code in the service in order to do some queries or to request some actions.

Your thinking sounds good but it may hides a complex implementation, If I was in your position I would consider to use the built in service mechanism called [Bound Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html). I have not used it so far but it seems that it is covering your needs.

EDIT

So based on the bound services concept I propose the following flow:

1. Activity starts, a so called, sticky service.
2. Service registers the receiver for network responces.
3. Service maintains an Ibinder object with the needed information based on the network responces.
4. Activity bounds to the service whenever it wants and retrieve the Ibinder object with the info and does the required actions.
5. When it's time to end the application, Activity stops the service and finishes itself.

Hope this helps...

Comment: thanks for your response. i'm not sure bound services helps, because you still need to unbind from the service when the activity is stopped, in which case you'd miss the messages coming back from the service.

Comment: The idea behind bound services is that another component (activity) in your application can connect to it at any time and retrieve any information. It is responsibility of the service  to maintain and provide this information to any component that bounds to it. This is pretty much the same concept you are thinking to implement with the difference that it is the andoid's built in mechanism for that purpose. I edited my answer to illustrate that approach.

Comment: the problem is that i want to ensure that every request / response pair is processed by the UI layer. with a bound service, it's still possible (i think) for the UI layer to make a call, then get paused, unbind, and miss the result. with a proper queue arrangement, the UI layer only takes from the queue when it is able to process the result.

Comment: [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) runs in the same thread as the UI but it will NOT stop during a call (this the difference with an activity). It will stop only if the system is LOW on resources or if it abuses the main thread with long operations (like networking). If you build your own queues they will be destroyed in a situation like this, there is nothing you can do to avoid it, except to persist their state and then reload it again. Every networking application I know uses services which spawn background threads for networking operations...

Comment: no, if i store a queue in the application class, it's only destroyed when the entire process is killed. i'm not worried about the service dying, i'm worried about when my activity has to unbind from the service because it's been stopped. as soon as it unbinds, it will not longer receive responses from the service.

Comment: TRUE. Activities destroyed all the time, but you can always re-bind to the service as soon as the activity is available again. You are not loosing anything because your queues are maintained inside the service (NOT in activity), this is the concept of the service. If you worry about re-starting the service will destroy your queues then DON'T. Each start command to a service does not re-create it if it is already running, that is the onCreate method of your service is only called once. Anyway I am also interested in a service-less solution, so if you come up with something let me know...